# How to Use python to show images on a 100 by 100 grid

Tags: python, image, grid

I have 10000 images and wanted to create a 100 by 100 grid to show the images.

EDIT:

With the code

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(7,10, figsize=(100, 100))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .005, wspace= .1)
axs = axs.ravel()
for i, img in enumerate(glob.glob('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tensorflow/indicator_result/*.jpg')):
    image = cv2.imread(img)
    axs[i].axis('off')
    axs[i].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    axs[i].set_title(img[-24:-13],fontsize= 60)
```

I can display, in this case, 7 rolls and 10 columns image with name on top of it.
Is there any way to save the whole 7 by 10 grid image to a single image?
[image]

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html this may help you

Comment: images are `numpy.array` which you can join to create one big array with all images and then you can display it with `plt.imshow()` or even with `cv2.imshow()`. You can also use `cv2.putText()` to add text to image.

Comment: you can generate HTML with `<table>` with `<img>` and names, save in file `.html` and display in web browser using `webbrowser.open("filename.html")` or somehow  display it directly in notebook.

Comment: @furas Could you show me an example? Thank you!

Comment: don't change original question because this way answers can seems useless. If you have new information then add at the end of old question.

Answer (score 1):

As for me it is the simplest to create HTML with `<table>` which has `<img>` and filename in every cell.

```
#filenames = df['FileName']
#filenames = glob.glob('*.jpg')
filenames = list(range(10000, 10200)) # (10000, 19999)

column_numbers = 10  # 100

html = '<html><body><table>'

for i, name in enumerate(filenames):
    # start row
    if i % column_numbers == 0:
        html += '<tr>'
        
    # cell in row
    html += f'<td>{name}<br/><img width="100" height="100" src="{name}"></td>'
    
    # end row
    if i % column_numbers == (column_numbers-1):
        html += '</tr>'

html += '</table></body></html>'
```

and then I could save it in file and open in web browser

```
fh = open('output.html', 'w')
fh.write(html)
fh.close()

import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('output.html')
```

or I could display directly in `Notebook`

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

display(HTML(html))
```

But this way it can't convert to greyscale and can't resize it.

`<img>` uses `width="100" height="100"` to display with size `100x100` but it reads full images and browser rescale them. Always it is faster to create smaller files with images `100x100` and later use only these smallers images.

---

Other method to create HTML with `<table>` is to create `DataFrame` with size `100x100` with all names and then use `df.to_html()` with formatter which will put `<img>` in cells

```
import pandas as pd

#filenames = glob.glob('*.jpg')
filenames = list(range(10000, 10200))  # (10000, 19999)

column_numbers = 10  # 100

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, len(filenames), column_numbers):
    df = df.append( [filenames[i:i+column_numbers]] )


# formatter    
def put_img(name):
    return f'{name}<br/><img width="100" height="100" src="{name}">'

# every column needs own formatter
#all_formatters = [put_img for _ in range(column_numbers)]
all_formatters = [put_img] * column_numbers

html = df.to_html(formatters=all_formatters, escape=False, header=False, index=False)

print(html)
```

and now again I would save in file and open with `webbrowser.open()` or I would use `IPython` to display it directly.

---

**EDIT:**

I made example which uses `subplots(rows_number, columns_number)` to create grid and later I put images in cells using `axs[row][col].imshow()`.

It automatically resize images and it can be good when you want resize window but for many images it may display very small images.

**EDIT:** to save it in file you can use `plt.savefig('image.jpg')` but it has to be before `plt.show()`

Doc: [savefig()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import math

path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tensorflow/0_180_direction_indicator/*.jpg'
filenames = glob.glob(path)

column_numbers = 5  # 100

# number of columns (width) and rows (height)
w = column_numbers
h = math.ceil(len(filenames) / column_numbers)

# create places for images
fig, axs = plt.subplots(h, w)

# remove axis for every image
for row in axs:
    for ax in row:
        ax.axis('off')

# display image
for i, name in enumerate(filenames):
    
    # calculate position 
    col = i % column_numbers
    row = i // column_numbers

    # read image
    img = plt.imread(name)
    
    # display image
    axs[row][col].imshow(img)
    
    # remove axis
    #axs[row][col].axis('off')
    
    # add title with filename without directory
    name = name.split('/')[-1] # keep only filename without directory
    axs[row][col].set_title(name)
    
# save in file - it has to be before `show()`
plt.savefig('image.jpg')

# display all 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I update the question. I want to save the whole image of the plt.show(). How should I do that?

Comment: you can use `plt.savefig('image.jpg')` but you have to do it before `plt.show()`. Doc: [savefig()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig)